# Do we need to normalized data for computing intraclass correlation coefficient?

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I want to calculate the ICC for data that have different scales. When I calculate ICC 1 way method with and without normalization data, the result is totally different. Do I need to normalize the data before computing the ICC?
Here is example of my data
[image]

Comment: There different ways to normalize data (fixed range, fixed variance, ...). What do you mean with "normalize"?

Comment: I used min-max normalization to scale data into 0-1 before I used ICC calculations.

Comment: Looking at the formulas for ICC1, there seems to be no simple invariance of this coefficient. Concerning ICC3 (the multi-rater case), there is however invariance with respect to the inter-rater variance: $MS_R$ in the denominator is the mean square of the row (all raters per item) sums, which is the second moment of the rater mean.